# Placing Python objects in shared memory

Tags: python, shared-memory, allocation

Is there a Python module that would enable me to place instances of non-trivial user classes into shared memory?

By that I mean allocating directly in shared memory as opposed to pickling into and out of it.

[`multiprocessing.Value`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value) and [`multiprocessing.Array`](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Array) wouldn't work for my use case as they only seem to support primitive types and arrays thereof.

The only thing I've found so far is [POSH](http://poshmodule.sourceforge.net/posh/html/), but it hasn't changed in eight years. This suggests that it's either super-stable or is out of date. Before I invest time in trying to get it work, I'd like to know if there are alternatives I haven't discovered yet.

I only need this to work on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's kind of a tough one. The best solution I can think of is pickling your objects and using a [c_char_p](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_char_p) with [multiprocessing.sharedctypes](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.sharedctypes). You'd still have to make sure no null bytes got into the c_char_p, either by escaping them or converting to hex.

On second thought, maybe you should go with POSH.