# Sharing Data in Python

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, pickle

I have some Pickled data, which is stored on disk, and it is about 100 MB in size.

When my python program is executed, the picked data is loaded using the `cPickle` module, and all that works fine.

If I execute the python multiple times using `python main.py` for example, each python process will load the same data multiple times, which is the correct behaviour.

How can I make it so, all new python process share this data, so it is only loaded a single time into memory?

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Unix, one possibility is to load the data into memory, and then have the script use [`os.fork()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.fork) to create a bunch of sub-processes. As long as the sub-processes don't attempt to *modify* the data, they would automatically share the parent's copy of it, without using any additional memory.

Unfortunately, this won't work on Windows.

P.S. I [once asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270849/placing-python-objects-in-shared-memory) about placing Python objects into shared memory, but that didn't produce any easy solutions.

Comment: *"automatically share the parent process's data, without using any additional memory"* not 100% true. It will be copy-on-write, so it will copy and will use additional memory as soon as you're going to access this data for modification.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how seriously you need to solve this problem, you may want to look at memcached, if that is not overkill.